# How to display callback function data into HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I am calling history API and able to print 10 result in console.log through JavaScript. Now I want to print that data into a HTML page. How can I display the result in HTML?

```js
chrome.history.search({'text': '', 'maxResults': 10},callback);

function callback(data){
console.log(data);
}
```

That is all the code in js file. I need help to process further. I've just started JavaScript.

Comment: in which element you want to show data?

Comment: Trying to show result  in a div given id display with a list of urls. The data provided by API is in array format

Answer (score 0):

Declare one global variable and assign value to it and use that variable in html code.

Example:

```
var htmlData=[];
function callback(data)
   {
    htmlData=data;
   }
```

Now use this htmlData in html code

Comment: The output says undefined only.one thing i forget to mention is API provide data in array format.

Comment: Try now with htmlData=[];